# I got missing executeable files after installing OpenJDK OpenJ9 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, jvm, ubuntu-18.04, openj9, adoptopenjdk

I recently installed OpenJ9 jvm in my Ubuntu 18.04 machine from https://launchpad.net/~rpardini/+archive/ubuntu/adoptopenjdk and got this notifications in my terminal:

```
    ** Missing executable /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-jdk- 
    openj9/bin/jcmd even though man page /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk- 
    11-jdk-openj9/man/man1/jcmd.1.gz exists.
    ** This is probably a bug in AdoptOpenJDK and should be reported 
    upstream.
    ** Missing executable /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-jdk- 
    openj9/bin/jinfo even though man page /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk- 
    11-jdk-openj9/man/man1/jinfo.1.gz exists.
    ** This is probably a bug in AdoptOpenJDK and should be reported 
    upstream.
    ** Missing executable /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-jdk-                                
    openj9/bin/jmap even though man page /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk- 
    11-jdk-openj9/man/man1/jmap.1.gz exists.
    ** This is probably a bug in AdoptOpenJDK and should be reported 
    upstream.
    ** Missing executable /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-jdk-                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    openj9/bin/jstat even though man page /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk- 
    11-jdk-openj9/man/man1/jstat.1.gz exists.
    ** This is probably a bug in AdoptOpenJDK and should be reported 
    upstream.
    ** Missing executable /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-jdk- 
    openj9/bin/jstatd even though man page 
    /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-jdk-openj9/man/man1/jstatd.1.gz 
    exists.
    ** This is probably a bug in AdoptOpenJDK and should be reported 
    upstream.
```

I have tried running Spring Tool Suit and so far no problem occured.

Should I worry about this?
If there is anything I could do to fix these missing files, please teach me. I have poor knowledge about how jvm works.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need jinfo, jstat or jstatd you can safely ignore those warnings from update-alternatives (those commands are not provided by OpenJ9). I opened an issue [1] suggesting that the man pages should only be included for commands that are provided.

Note that jcmd and jmap have been added in more recent versions of OpenJ9.

[1] https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/issues/8732